# Cannot read from DS3231

Tags: esp8266, i2c, rtc

I'm having issues with a DS3231 RTC connected to an ESP8266. I can write to it to set the time (`Wire.write` returns 1), but anytime I try to read from it, `Wire.requestFrom` always returns 0.
I've tested my circuit with another DS3231 and it works correctly. So I guess it's faulty hardware and I can throw it to the bin. Or is there something I can do with it?

Update:
In fact, `endTransmission` returns 2, which if I understand well means the address is not found, so this is not a read issue. I guess that means it's dead.

Comment: `Wire.write()` only places data in the TX buffer. Please check the return value od `Wire.endTransmission()`, which is doing the actual communication. Have you checked with the I2C Scanner sketch, if the Arduino sees the DS on the Wire bus

Comment: @chrisl I hadn't thought of that, thx. See my edits.

Comment: Have you tried the I2C scanner sketch? Are you using pullup resistors on the lines?

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it finds nothing. I'm using the integrated pullups on the esp8266 (huzzah board). Also, the circuit works correctly if just drop another one in place.